# JOIN not producing results

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a daily figure view and a monthly figure view.

DAILY view:

```
 SELECT * (includes sum)
 FROM
 Person
 FULL OUTER JOIN Profit 
 ON Person.id = Profit.id
 AND Profit.[DATE] = CAST(getdate () -1  as Date)
```

Now this returns 70 rows.

MONTHLY view:

```
 SELECT * (includes sum)
 FROM
 Person
 FULL OUTER JOIN Profit
 ON Person.id = profit.id
 WHERE 
 [DATE] BETWEEN CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + '01/' +  + 
 CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
 AND  GETDATE()
```

This returns 40 rows.

Now in my select statement i want to return all rows from the daily view regardless of whether there is a match in the monthly view.

Now i thought something like this would work:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM  
 DailyView
 LEFT JOIN
 MonthlyView
 ON DailyView.id = MonthlyView.id
```

But this only returns 40 rows. I have also tried full outer join but this still only returns 40 rows. What could be the reason for this? Thanks

Comment: You should show sample data and desired results.  The `FULL OUTER JOIN` is suspicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is undoing the `outer join`.

You can fix your problem by moving the conditions to the `ON` clause and removing the `WHERE` clause.

Your query is suspicious in its use of `FULL OUTER JOIN`.  `FULL OUTER JOIN` is not generally needed when joining tables on well-defined keys.

Comment: I have tried normal joins but it produces the same result. The keys are not well defined

Comment: >>>Your WHERE clause is undoing the outer join<<< That is not true, the last query does not have WHERE clause at all

Comment: His views do not need full join, it's true, but how it's related to the final result?

Comment: I need a full outer in original join because there are nulls in both that i need

Comment: @sepupic . . . The last query doesn't even refer to the same tables as the first two queries.  Presumably, the references to `dailyview` or `monthlyview` are to the original queries, which do have `where` clauses.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I understood directly, i.e. that the last query uses 2 views, texts of these views are published. Both views are in fact RIGHT joins because they filter on right table column, but final query is left join query that has no WHERE clause and is correct

Answer (score 0):

The monthly view must

```
SELECT * (includes sum)
 FROM
 Person
 FULL OUTER JOIN Profit
 ON Person.id = profit.id
 AND [DATE] BETWEEN CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + '01/' +  + 
 CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
 AND  GETDATE()
```